# Does Google Drive File Stream work for multiple accounts?

Tags: google-drive, google-drive-file-stream

Until summer 2020, G Suite customers used Google File Stream to get files onto their computers, and Gmail users were limited to Backup and Sync. As of July 2020, Gmail users we allowed to use File Stream, and as of January 2020, they were even encouraged to switch from Backup and Sync to File Stream via in-app notification.

Also as of July 2020, a significant downside to using File Stream is that it didn't support multiple accounts, instead requiring users to log out of one account and into another one (see [article](https://www.androidpolice.com/2020/09/24/personal-gmail-accounts-can-now-try-g-suites-file-stream-to-sync-drive-content-to-their-computers/) and [support forum](https://support.google.com/a/thread/11506551?hl=en)).

I might expect for this single-account limitation to be gone now that Google is encouraging all users to adopt File Stream. Is that the case? I can't find any documentation on Google's [support sites](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/7638428).

Comment: This is a disguised plea for a feature. The link cited in your question answers your question. https://support.google.com/a/thread/11506551/is-it-possible-to-use-multiple-accounts-with-google-drive-file-stream?hl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does as of June 12, 2021.

> June 12, 2021 - Drive for desktop support for Backup and Sync features
>
> Windows and macOS: Version 49.0
>
> - Ability to sign in with **up to four** Google accounts at once.

source: [https://support.google.com/a/answer/7577057?hl=en#:~:text=Ability%20to%20sign%20in%20with%C2%A0up%20to%20four%20Google%20accounts%20at%20once](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7577057?hl=en#:%7E:text=Ability%20to%20sign%20in%20with%C2%A0up%20to%20four%20Google%20accounts%20at%20once).

Answer (score 1):

I have installed Google Drive File Stream v 44.0.14.0, on Windows 10 Single Language (Spanish). At this time it doesn't allow me to sign-in into multiple accounts, so I think that your expectations aren't met... yet.

By the way on [Upcoming Google Workspace releases](https://support.google.com/a/table/7539891?hl=en) there is only one mention of File Stream

```
| Pin non-Docs, Sheets, and Slides files so     |   In beta. [Learn more]*   |
| that they're available offline through        |                            |
| Google Drive's web interface, together with   |                            |
| Drive File Stream.                            |                            |
```

- [Learn more](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2019/06/drive-offline-binary-beta.html)

Another resource is [Google Drive File Stream release notes](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7577057?hl=en). As of February 3, 2021 the upcoming support of multiple accounts is not mentioned.